# Setting the innerHTML of an already rendered elment in react.js to be a component

Tags: reactjs

Am working with the ionic ui library in react.js and here is my code

```
 <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
      {page.tabs.map(tab => {
        const Icon = Icons[`${tab.icon}`];

        return (
          <IonTabButton>
            <Icon
              style={{
                fontSize: "20px"
              }}
            />
            <IonLabel
              style={{
                fontSize: "14px"
              }}
            >
              {" "}
              {tab.text}{" "}
            </IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
        );
      })}
    </IonTabBar>
  </IonTabs>
```

And when renders on the browser it has this

```
 <div>
  <div class="tabs-inner"> </div>
  <ion-tab-bar>
    <ion-tab-button>
      <svg>
       .....
      </svg>
      <ion-label>
        user
      </ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</div>
```

Now i would like to inject a component into the class "tabs-inner" so my soultion was to give the div a ref and find it using

```
 const tab = tabsRef.current.getElementsByClassName('tabs-inner')[0]
```

Now I would like to inject a component into the div with the `tabs-inner` class say

```
tab.innerHTML = 'am here'
```

That works but if I try

```
tab.innerHTML = <Mycomponent/>
```

it doesn't, am trying to set the innerHTML to be a tag so I can inject components into it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Typically in React we render components in the `render()` method of a class or return JSX from a function. We can update a component's state in order to force it to be rendered again. I suggest using this mechanism as it is intended rather than circumventing it by manipulating the DOM directly with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Or perhaps I misunderstand. Nothing in your question is about ReactJS even though you have the reactjs tag. Can you provide a minimal, complete example that shows what you are doing in the context of the surrounding code?

Comment: thanks but i think you didn't but i have edited my question to be more descriptive of my problem

Comment: Using Vanilla JavaScript to modify the DOM defeats the purpose of using ReactJS in the first place. Instead, you should figure out what React component and JSX code renders the `<div>` you want to modify and edit that JSX code to render what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your component to be rendered in the state of the Component and render it accordingly. In case if you do not want to render anything at a particular time, you can set that state key to null.

```
constrcutor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        componentToRender: null
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            componentToRender: <b>Hello World</b>
        });
    }, 1000);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="">
            { this.state.componentToRender }
        </div>
    );
}
```

In the above example, I am just setting the HTML after 1 second but you can set the data whenever you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot but this isnt what am looking for though i think am gonna have to explain a bit further in the question

Answer (score -1):

So after doing a bit of digging, I found a not so wise way to do it using the `react-dom` import  `hydrate`

```
import { hydrate } from "react-dom";
.........
const tab = tabsRef.current.getElementsByClassName("tabs-inner")[0];
hydrate(
  <Canvas/>,
  tab
);
```

This works for most cases and would have worked cool for me but am using redux in my canvas container and it is generating other errors.